# for-loop counter gives an unused-variable warning

Tags: c++, for-loop, gcc-warning, unused-variables, iota

My program has an iterative algorithm with a for-loop that I had written as

```
for ( auto i: std::views::iota( 0u, max_iter ) ) { ... }
```

I really like the fact that it can be written like this, even if the necessary header files are enormous. When I compile it though I get a warning that `i` is an unused variable.

When I write the for-loop in the old-fashioned way

```
for ( unsigned i=0; i < max_iter; i++ ) { ... }
```

then there is no warning.

I tested this with a minimal program `for-loop.cpp`:

```
#include<ranges>
#include<numeric>
#include<iostream>

int main() {

    char str[13] = "this is good";

    for (auto i : std::views::iota(0u, 2u)) {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    }
  
    for (unsigned it=0; it<2; it++ ) {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

and sure enough, compiling it with `g++ -Wall --std=c++20 -o for-loop for-loop.cpp` gives a warning for the first loop and not the second.

Am I missing something here? I prefer the first notation -- and I know that I can stop the warnings wit `-Wno-unused-variables`; I would like those warnings, it's just that I am really using the for-loop counter.

Comment: In the second example `i` is considered "used" in the loop boundary check and the loop increment.  Do you still get the warning if you rename `i` to `_` in the first example?

Comment: Also consider using `[[maybe_unused]]` instead of disabling the warning globally in general. Although not in that case, renaming `i` to `_` should be sufficient.

Comment: @0x5453 - Yes, then it gives the warning for the name '_'

Comment: Does `while (std::views::iota( 0u, max_iter ) ) { ... }` give you the same unused variable warning?

Comment: @Tommy-XavierRobillard ah yes, `[[maybe_unused]]` does the trick! I did not know that syntax, thanks very much!

Comment: `for ( auto i: std::views::iota( 0u, max_iter ) ) { ... }` seems very complicated, harder to read, understand and maintain compared to the corresponding plain `for` loop. A programmers primary goal (IMO) should be good, clean, readable, easily understandable, and maintainable code. But most importantly it should be *simple*.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb - that gives an error that there is `no viable conversion` from the range to a boolean

Comment: An idiomatic way of making a variable "used" with no side effect is to cast it to void. Adding `(void)i;` inside the loop body will fix this kind of problem in every version of C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I came across this notation when I was looking for a way to write a loop more similar to python (or matlab). Other than the scope identifiers that make it a bit longer, I think it is a very readable notation. To me the fact that `i` only appears once in there makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is indeed never used.

You might add attribute [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) (C++17) to ignore that warning:

```
for ([[maybe_unused]]auto i : std::views::iota(0u, 2u)) {
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Works only with STD C++ 17 and above.

Comment: Though idiomatic, this looks too heavy. I would appreciate if there was a way to disable this warning for variables named `_`.

Answer (score 2):

With the `auto i` you never use the variable anywhere.

With the `for ( unsigned i=0; i < max_iter; i++ )` you're using `i` twice, once in `i < max_iter` and again in `i++` so the variable is used